# magento 2 rest api variable type

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento-2.0

I created web api and trying to validate entered data `":postcode"`.

Here is code in etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
        <route url="/V1/postcode/check/:postcode" method="GET">
            <service class="Modules\ShippingMethod\Api\Data\PostcodeInterface" method="check"/>
            <resources>
                <resource ref="anonymous"/>
            </resources>
        </route>
    </routes>
```

When I send

```
curl http://site.dev/rest/default/V1/postcode/check/0003
```

the `var_dump()` inside `"check"` method gives me an integer value `"3"`, but I need to get full variable with all zero symbols and, maybe, specify string type for it. How can I specify variable type or get full request variable?

Answer (score 0):

Are you annotation for method Modules\ShippingMethod\Api\Data\PostcodeInterface::check($postcode) define $postcode as int?  If yes, change it to string to resolve problem